R - 95 CI for rmse from lmer
Is it possible to get the 95 CI for rmse? Thank you
library(lme4)
library(performance)
 

dat <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/demo3.csv")

m1  <-  lmer(pulse ~  time + (1 | id), data = dat)

#icc
icc(m1, ci=0.95, ci_method = "boot")
    
# TEM/rmse
performance_rmse(m1, normalized = FALSE)

Any help is appreciated.

Have a look at the bootMer function. It requires that you enter the function that returns the statistic of interest. Your code will look something like bootMer(m1, function(x) performance_rmse(x, normalized = FALSE), 200)
